# Change templates/views location in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I will be working on project that has different theme for each domain (same application will be serving multiple domains).

1. I need to change location of templates completely outside the application folder, possible on another volume
2. I need to make it work with multiple domains with multiple themes - i guess theres cache problem

S how to do this stuff with Symfony2 and twig?

EDIT: I will try to ask this: What or where do I need to rewrite to get custom logic on locating specific templates that symfony uses to render pages.

Comment: Is it correct all I need to do is rewrite TemplateReference? But I dont understans how they did it here then: https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if first point of your question is a bad practice (and don't know even if it possible, but I would say yes).

However, what I would do is some kind of "manager" that will takes responsibility for choosing what kind of template render, based onto your own logic. Some kind of "intermediate level" between actions and views.

You could create it as a service and use everywhere, without have need to instantiate it every time.
It could read a file for configuration or, even (but less springy), use a class-internal configuration.

Algorithm could be something like this:

- Take into account your request
- "Eat" data and "spit out" the correct template (name)
- Pass template (name) to your view
- Extend (dinamically) the template given by your manager

Please, don't ask me some code because it could result in some hundred lines :)

Comment: Yes I count on it, it must be at least 100 lines of code and several classes actually - caching and template location. I am just asking what classes or what services, how do I tell Symfony to use my template locating system and what do I need to take care of.

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič: You have to write your own service, based on your own rules and pass the reponse (template to render) to your view that will simply render it

Comment: There has to be other way, something like rewriting some template locator. I dont believe only solution is to pass that specific template to render in controller in each action.

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič: I suppose that is the only solution. Or, maybe, you can call a sort of "beforeStart" action where you can set inside the "global" template all the things you're searching for.....
But I'm not expert of twig, so maybe listen to other advices (if any) :)

Comment: https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle - look at this. I just have to find out how it works and do it my way.

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič: you ask for "application theming", that bundle speak about "bundle theming" that is quite different

Comment: Well, I guess I need both then, dont I? I still wanna use the default location strategy (as failover), but I need it to first check it my new locations. EDIT: What is the difference between changing bundle and application templating?

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič: without take a look to bundle code, I suppose that use bundle template is something like: every couple of action/views that belong to template A, will have A template, every couple of action/views of template B, will have B template and so on....
Generally, an application is made of more than one bundle, so if I don't misunderstand your question, this kind of bundle isn't suitable for your needs (or maybe you could set the same template for every bundle?)
However, I suppose that your application will use the same bundle for every domains, so if you wan to change [...]

Comment: [...] skin based on domain, I suppose that only bundle theming isn't enaugh. Hope you can understand my point of view :)